# Why does Java Compiler refuse to compile this?

Tags: java

Why does Java Compiler raise "The local variable s may not have been initialized" in the finally block. I can not figure out in which flow of code, **s** remains un-initialized.

```
 public static void test() {
    String s;
    try {
        s = "abc";
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        s = "throwable";
    } finally {
        System.out.println(s.getClass()); //---->(The local variable s may not have been initialized)
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361916/why-does-the-java-compiler-complain-about-a-local-variable-not-having-been-initi?rq=1

Comment: Because local variable has not been initialized.

Comment: what if code in catch branch fails

Comment: If the assignment in catch block fails as well, then it may not have been initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an OutOfMemory-Error in line 6, s cant be used in line 8.

Comment: does the Java Language Specification speak anything about the execution of the finally block in cases like OutOfMemory-Error?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: JLS, section 14.20.2. The finally block is always executed, even if a new throwable is thrown in the catch block.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes "to ensure that resource is always recovered." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @Peter: Error is a subclass of Throwable. I wrote throwable on purpose, since it doesn't matter if an Exception or Error is thrown in the catch block. The finally block is executed no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the java language specification is that local variables must be explicitly initialized before use (ie before its value is referenced).

There are `Throwables` that would prevent `s` from being given a value - `OutOFMemoryError` being one of them.

Giving `s` a value will fix the compile problem:

```
String s = null;
```

The reason explicit initialization is required is that local variables use stack memory, not the heap memory as for instance variables, and there's no construction phase to give a default value to the variable - it has to be coded.

Comment: Yes but I think the OP is stating that `s` _will_ be set in either the `try` or the `catch`.

Comment: @Bohemian, clearly, there are 2 possible flows.1) Normal flow: where a="abc". (2)Exceptional flow: s="throwable". In either cases, **s** is initialized.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, (3) double exceptional flow:  another exception is thrown from within the `catch` block

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler can't guarantee 100% that the assignment in the `try` block will run without any problems and similarly with the `catch` block. And if both assignments fail, `s` will be still uninitialized when it is printed in the `finally` block which isn't legal.

Answer (score 1):

> > I can not figure out in which flow of code, s remains un-initialized.

Theoretically, an exception may occur in `try/catch` block, for instance `OutOfMemoryException`. For avoid this, You can initialize `s` with `null`

```
String s = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there can be a new exception in the catch block before s is initialized. For example an OutOfMemoryError.